In-line function command different whether it is followed by a dot or not
I have defined a command to automatize a trick to write functions "in-line". That way, I have $f : E \longrightarrow F$ aligned with the text (see below) and the action on the elements is underneath, which is what I want.
My problem is: when I finish a sentence with that command, the period appears with a space, and I would like to automatize something : when the following symbols of the commands are $ + space, nothing happens ; when it is $ + dot, it puts the dot within my command just after the third argument AND obviously it deletes the real dot I have written.
I think it could be possible with the ifthen package. I would write two different commands but I don't know how to analyse "following symbols".
Any idea?
Here's a MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\fonction}[5]{\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
#1 : &  #2 &\longrightarrow #3\\
     &  \hspace*{\fill} #4 &\longmapsto #5
\end{array}}

\begin{document}

We define a function $\fonction{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}$.

\end{document}


Please note that nowadays you don't need \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} anymore as that's the default in LaTeX.

OK, duly noted!

you get ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \fonction.  the desired markup with . after the $ is really odd, and as egere suggests the notation seems far more suited to display math than inline

Using \fonction inline will irremediably spoil the line spacing. If you really want to use it (I came to find it obnoxious) , do so only in displays.

I honestly think it's better to not automate this. Anyway the following implements it.
It uses \NewDocumentCommand to implement this. We use !t$ to test for an immediately following $ (no space allowed), and after that !t. to check for the dot.
Note that the mechanism of \NewDocumentCommand will absorb the . even if the $ doesn't immediately follow, so we need to check things to reinsert the dot if no $ was there, and only insert an earlier dot if both were there. Additionally we need to reinsert the $ if it was absorbed.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{array}

\NewDocumentCommand\fonction{m m m m m !t$ !t.}
  {%
    \begin{array}[t]{rcl}
      #1 : &  #2 &\longrightarrow #3\IfBooleanT{#6}{\IfBooleanT{#7}.}\\
           &  \hspace*{\fill} #4 &\longmapsto #5
    \end{array}
    \IfBooleanTF{#6}{$}{\IfBooleanT{#7}{.}}%
  }

\begin{document}

We define a function $\fonction{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}$.

\end{document}


I would not use this, certainly not in inline math but

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\def\tmptest{$.}
\newcommand{\fonction}[7]{%
\def\tmp{#6#7}%
\begin{array}[t]{rcl}
#1 : &  #2 &\longrightarrow #3\ifx\tmp\tmptest.\fi\\
     &  \hspace*{\fill} #4 &\longmapsto #5
\end{array}%
\ifx\tmp\tmptest\expandafter$%
\else\expandafter\tmp\fi
}

\begin{document}

We define a function $\fonction{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}$.


We define a function $\fonction{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}$ no dot.


\end{document}


You can use \peek_regex:nTF. I present the examples in context, so you can see why I recommend not to use this pedantic constructions. It might be good for displays, definitely not inline.
I also fixed the excess space you have in your array.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\NewDocumentCommand\fonctioninner{mmmmm}{%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}r@{}l@{}}
    #1\colon &  #2 &{}\longrightarrow #3 \\
             &  #4 &{}\longmapsto #5
    \end{array}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\fonction}{mmmmm}
 {
  \peek_regex_remove_once:nTF { \s* (?:\$|\c{\)}) \.}
   {% there are end of formula and period
    \fonctioninner{#1}{#2}{#3.}{#4}{#5}$
   }
   {
    \fonctioninner{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

We define a function $\fonction{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}$. Next, we see how
bad for the spacing $\fonction{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}$ is. You can easily
notice that the vertical space is irremediably spoiled, which makes
reading very awkward.
Now I add some nonsense words.
Now I add some nonsense words.
Now I add some nonsense words.
Now I add some nonsense words.
Now I add some nonsense words.
Now I add some nonsense words.
Now I add some nonsense words.
Finally I show it also works with the other math mode delimiter
and define a function \(\fonction{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}\).
The same considerations as above apply: the line spacing is
really awful.

\end{document}


Now I present how I'd do it avoiding Bourbaki style.


You could make the macro \fonction take an optional argument. The default optional argument could be set to blank, but you might specify . in order to place a period at the end of the first line. Oh, and I think you can get by with 2 rather than 3 columns in the array environment. Finally, you may want to think about replacing : in row 1 with \colon.

\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\fonction}[6][]{% default value of optional arg. is empty
   \begin{array}[t]{@{} r @{\;} l @{}}
       #2 : #3 &\longrightarrow #4 \, #1\\
            #5 &\longmapsto     #6
   \end{array}%
}

\begin{document}
We define a function $\fonction[.]{f}{E}{F}{x}{f(x)}$
\end{document}

